# I am trying to do looping but I can't

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, for-loop

I am trying to make `for` loops using date function but I can't. In my case, I am trying to loop 2001-feb to 2009-jan and want to insert date but I can't. Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
for($start_year; $start_year<= $end_year; $start_year++)
{
  for($start_month; $start_month<= $end_month; $start_month++)
  {
    $date_input = $start_year."-".$start_month."-27";
  }
}
```

Comment: PHP and mysql and i am useing codeingniter

Comment: For future questions: please put things like that into the **tags** of your question! Thanks

Comment: Please post the results that you are getting as well. If you're getting an error, please post the error.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like PHP.

```
for($start_year; $start_year<= $end_year; $start_year++)
```

You've not specified a starting value for `$start_year`, so unless you've defined that variable elsewhere, this is a syntax error. As well, since you're starting/ending on different months, you can't really use a loop for that without jumping through hoops. You'd probably be better off with something like this:

```
$date = strtotime("2001-02-01 00:00:00");
$end = strtotime("2009-01-01 00:00:00");

do {
   echo date('Y-m', $date), "-27";
   $date = strtotime("+1 month", $date);
} while ($date <= $end);
```

Note that [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) is only one way of doing this. You could use the [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) object with a 1-month [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), but that's for PHP 5.3+ only.